# adding document to collection failed in Solr cloud mode

Tags: solr

I need to add all documents in a folder to collection and it failed:

Here is my command:

```
hostname: mysolr
Solr Admin URL: http://mysolr.net:8983/solr/#/
Collection name: collection_indexer
Collection url: http://mysolr.net:8983/solr/#/collection_indexer_shard1_replica1
```

data folder:

```
/tmp/solr_data
```

Running folder:

```
bash-4.1$ pwd
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars
```

command:

```
java -Dtype=application/json -Drecursive -Durl="http://mysolr.net:8983/solr/#/collection_indexer_shard1_replica1/update/json/docs" -jar post.jar /tmp/solr_data
```

Output:

> bash-4.1$ java -Dtype=application/json -Drecursive
>   -Durl="http://mysolr.net:8983/solr/#/collection_indexer_shard1_replica1/update/json/docs"
>   -jar post.jar /tmp/solr_data SimplePostTool version 1.5 Posting files to base url
>   http://mysolr.net:8983/solr/#/collection_indexer_shard1_replica1/update/json/docs
>   using content-type application/json.. Entering recursive mode, max
>   depth=999, delay=0s Indexing directory /tmp/solr_data (1 files,
>   depth=0) POSTing file test.json SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned
>   an error #405 (Method Not Allowed) for url:
>   http://mysolr.net:8983/solr/#/collection_indexer_shard1_replica1/update/json/docs
>   SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: Apache
>   Tomcat/6.0.45 - Error report
>
> ## 525D76;}--> HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
>
> noshade="noshade">
>
> **type** Status report
>
> **message**
>   HTTP method POST is not supported by this
>   URL
>
> **description** The specified HTTP method is not
>   allowed for the requested resource.
>
> #### Apache Tomcat/6.0.45
>
> SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response:
>   java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL:
>   http://mysolr.net:8983/solr/#/collection_indexer_shard1_replica1/update/json/docs
>   1 files indexed. COMMITting Solr index changes to
>   http://mysolr.net:8983/solr/#/collection_indexer_shard1_replica1/update/json/docs..
>   Time spent: 0:00:00.100

I also tried: http://mysolr.net:8983/solr/#/collection_indexer/update/json/docs as the Durl and got same error message.

Note the end of error message seems to give hint that the error pertains to the url or REST, can you please clarify what is missing here?

Thank you very much.

**Update 20180415 7:07am EST:**

Following MatsLindh's comment below, I made change to the command and ran again with the new command

```
java -Dtype=application/json -Drecursive -Durl="http://dsnyr001d01i1d.nam.nsroot.net:8983/solr/collection_indexer_shard1_replica1/update" -jar post.jar /tmp/solr_data
```

> SimplePostTool version 1.5 Posting files to base url
>   http://mysolr.net:8983/solr/collection_indexer_shard1_replica1/update
>   using content-type application/json.. Entering recursive mode, max
>   depth=999, delay=0s Indexing directory /tmp/solr_data (1 files,
>   depth=0) POSTing file test.json SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned
>   an error #400 (Bad Request) for url:
>   http://mysolr.net:8983/solr/collection_indexer_shard1_replica1/update
>   SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response:
>   {"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":0},"error":{"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException","root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],"msg":"Unknown
>   command: region [9]","code":400}} SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException
>   while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP
>   response code: 400 for URL:
>   http://mysolr.net:8983/solr/collection_indexer_shard1_replica1/update
>   1 files indexed. COMMITting Solr index changes to
>   http://mysolr.net:8983/solr/collection_indexer_shard1_replica1/update..
>   Time spent: 0:00:00.100

This time it is 400 error.

From Solr Admin I still do not see the new document is added.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally sorted it out with the below steps (exceptions showing in the log /var/log/solr):

```
1. Manually created new schema file specifically for the data format
2. Update the instance and the schema
solrctl instancedir --update
solrctl collection --reload
3. make sure the id for each doc is unique
```

Thanks lots to MatsLindh for the enlightening. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Any part after a `#` in a standard HTTP URL is an anchor, and meant for consumption on the client (usually by scrolling to the element with the anchor as its `id`). These days it's used more for keeping state for browser applications (in particular before the history state API was introduced).

The important part is that anything behind `#` is never transmitted to the server - it's only used by the client to either scroll the page or used by javascript in the browser to handle state (in this case - which page you actually were looking at).

Since it's never transmitted to the server you end up making a request to  `http://mysolr.net:8983/solr/` - which probably isn't the URL you want to query.

Drop the anchor and use the actual collection update URL: `http://mysolr.net:8983/solr/collection_indexer/update/json/docs` should work.

You should not have to use the direct core URL (i.e. with the shard/replica parameters) if you're running in cloud mode.

Comment: Thank you MatsLindh, please see my new output in the original post.

Comment: You're not using the URL you originally said you were going to use (and which I used in my example). If you're POST-ing to just `/update` (and please, use the collection URL without shard and replica given - there shouldn't be a reason to use those directly for your use case). If you're going to use just /update, you have to format the document as Solr expects and not submit random JSON. See [Uploading data with index handlers](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html)

Comment: Yes, as I said - if you're going to add random JSON, you have to use the `update/json/docs` URL - which is what you said you're using, and not just the `update` endpoint. The `update` endpoint expects the JSON message formatted a special way.

Comment: Thank you MatsLindh, as you can see from the new screenshot, it is still throwing error 400. https://snag.gy/GcOqpU.jpg

Comment: And the error message is telling you what the problem is - `Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id`. The default configuration has the id field set as the uniqueKey for all documents, and the field has to be present so that you can reference a document uniquely. If you don't have an id field, you can [add an update chain](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/update-request-processors.html) with a `UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory` to generate uuids for each document. Be aware that you won't get automagic updates of existing documents in that case.

Comment: I can assure the document has uniqueKey field: id; I can assure the document's fields are all included in the schema.xml, and still not able to index the document. However it is noticed that if I use existing fields in the default schema.xml and apply the names to the document's fields name then it can be index'ed, I am wondering the Solr server doesn't take the updated schema, maybe missing one step? Thank you.

Comment: If you've changed the schema outside of Solr, you have to reload the core or collection to make Solr detect it. You can do this under the core/collection page under the Solr Admin interface.